# Are SVG image files safe to upload? Why WP defines them as a security risk?

Tags: security, svg

I'd like to upload a map of the USA in a SVG format however I am prevented from doing so because of a 'security risk'.

Any ideas why this is? Is it safe to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG files contain code in the XML markup language which is similar to HTML. Your browser or SVG editing software parses the XML markup language to display the output on the screen.

However, this opens up your website to possible XML vulnerabilities. It can be used to gain unauthorized access to user data, trigger brute force attacks, or cross-site scripting attacks.

[Detailed article here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-svg-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks - and very interesting....I guess just sticking with 'traditional formats' is best then if you want to be 100% safe.